# Mark a method anonymous: swagger version 3.0.2

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I am using [Swagger-ui version 3.0.2](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), I have hosted it locally and provided it my Json file and API it opens the document fine and lists all the method in the json file, after i put basic authentication in it, i did changes in the .JSON file, but there are some methods which i want to mark anonymous.

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "description": "description",
        "version": "1.0",
        "title": "API"
    },
    "host": "localhost",
    "schemes": [
        "http"
    ],
    "securityDefinitions": {
        "anonymous_auth": {
            "type": ""
        },
        "basic_auth": {
            "type": "basic",
            "name": "basic_auth",
            "description": "Basic Authentication"
        },
        "token": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "description": "API Token Authentication",
            "name": "apikey",
            "in": "header"
        }
    },
    "security": [
        {
            "basic_auth": [ ]
        },
        {
            "token": [ ]
        }
    ],
    "paths": {
        //somthing
    },
    "definitions": {  
        //something    
    }
}
```

By using **security** atribute in this way it will secure complete file, but i have some methods which should be anonymous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove global `security`, add an empty `security` array to the operation:

```
"paths": {
  "/something:": {
    "get": {
      "security": [],
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Also, your spec is not valid:

1. Remove `anonymous_auth`.
2. Remove `name` from `basic_auth` - `name` is only used in `apiKey` security schemes to specify the name of the header or query parameter that will contain the API key.

Comment: I want to remove LOCK sign from the method, which will denotes it as anonymous method.

Comment: This will remove the lock sign from these operations in Swagger UI. Did you try this?